# p:dataTable selection copy to clipboard

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to create a button that will copy the clipboard to the selection made on a table developed with primefaces but I can not do it I looked on the net but could not find anything to do for my case. can you help me, thank you so much for any help

Comment: Which is the part you couldn't do precisely?

Comment: sorry but my English is bad do not understand the question

Comment: For example, can you create a button otherwise? Can you copy anything to clipboard? Which is the part you can't do? Unless you really do mean all of it - in which case I can't help unfortunately :(

Comment: I honestly did not know I would need to begin to place a button next to each line of the datatable and its action and that we copy the text of the line to the clipboard. Thanks for the help

Comment: I can't figure out if you want to copy from the system clipboard to the `p:dataTable` or from the `p:dataDatable` to the system clipboard.  Anyhow, this question is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/1980659.